# Bootstrap creates some sort of margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using bootstrap to build the base of a website it creates some weird black, the black color is the body's color, margin on the right side of the header.

HTML:

```
<section id="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="right">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="featured">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box yellow">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box blue">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box red">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 box green">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box gray">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 box white">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000;
}
.content-wrapper {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
section#header {
    background: white;
    height: 150px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
.gray {
    background: gray;
}
.white {
    background: white;
}
.box {
    height: 250px;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awu2cp6a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black on the right side is the background color.

The reason you only see it there is, because `.row` has `margin-left/right: 15px;`. If you remove/overwrite this to 0px, the black disappears or you add the `row` class to the element with the image.

**EDIT**

So if you would have an image, it would be OVER the black area, but because there is no image that fits in the full size, it's not displaying. Have you tryed give your section the row class?

Comment: Both alternatives worked out! Thanks, but why does row have a margin-left and right?

Comment: I think just for visual things. So it looks like it's INSIDE the box and not right at the edge. If you look at the "Add Comment" button, the text also is not on the edge, but ~10px away from left and right side. If you follow the -perfect- bootstrap way, everything should fit without much changes, but you can't always go straight the bootstrap way. If you have to change something, overwrite them -after- the bootstrap part. Means first `<link rel="stylesheet" href="cdn.bootstrap...."><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">` this order.